# Embed images or link to external images in emails in legitimate mass mailings

Tags: email

It turns out to be quite easy to [send emails with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net) that use embedded images. By embedding I mean actually include the image as an MIME attachment.

I'm just trying to figure out whether or not I should embed images as resources for mass mailings (to opt-in / existing customers). Alternatively I would just reference images with a `<img src>`

**Reasons for embedding images**

- Spam filters may be less likely to block emails - because no tracking pixels exist
- Email clients may be more likely to show the images - because no tracking pixels exist
- Available for offline viewing
- We don't need to host the images indefinitely

**Reasons for not embedding images (IMG src attribute pointing to an external site)**

- Spam filters may be more likely to block large files if we have lots of images
- We get to host the images and change them if we made a mistake
- We can track views of emails in server logs
- Blasting out a tonne of emails should take a lot less time
- We take less of a server bandwidth hit for the hosted images555
- Sending out many emails with embedded images may take a long time becuse we have to send 400kb for each email

I'm sure there are more reasons.

I'm most concerned about spam related issues. Curious for anybody's input

Comment: Bump? Would love an answer to this.

Comment: @Omar Me to, what are peoples experiences with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can at least check the spam-score of the email you've created. Checking two versions with and without embedded images. A lot of mailing applications (mass-mailers) offer some sort of spam check functionality. Or you could use a tool like: http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try base64 embedding?

http://yellowgreen.de/image-to-base64-string-encoder