# Sending an email with an image embedded in the body from C#

Tags: c#, email, image, client, embedding

My problem is how to send an email with attachemnts to the default mail client programmatically.

My requirements are:

1. setting destination, CC, BCC
2. link to attachment(s)
3. adding and image like a banner in the message body

I succeded to compose an email in the various ways and adding attachments are not
the problem but adding an embedded image is.

I had composed the message body as HTML and had integrated the image Base64 encoded but Outlook and Outlook Express does not recognized the image. Why?

Does anybody have a solution to my problems.

I solved a part of my problems calling MAPI.

Comment: Hai patrik, Have a look at this [Sending Email with an embedded image](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/95_Sending_Email_using_C__and_ASPNet_20.aspx) and this [sending email with image](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/inkrajesh.aspx) or this in Stack overflow
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net)

Comment: Don't forget to mark  the @Oscar answer as a correct one.

Comment: Check this link.  it has ready to use method for multiple inline  attachment as well as for general attachment  for pdf/excel files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665280/add-multiple-images-in-the-email-body-inlineusing-c-sharp-windows-application/49329461#49329461