# Attach a Chart - image to an email body - Beginner

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I need to send an email that contains a pie chart in the body of the email.

The Pie chart that is being included in the email body should have 25% of it filled.

So far i have sorted the email code. Here's the code.

- This is a VB forms application.

  ```
  Try
      Dim Smtp As New SmtpClient
      Dim em As New MailMessage()
      Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
      Smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx")
      Smtp.Port = 587
      Smtp.EnableSsl = True
      Smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

      em= New MailMessage()
      em.From = New MailAddress("xx@gmail.com")
      em.To.Add("y@y.com")
      em.Subject = "Pie Chart attached to email body"
      em.IsBodyHtml = True
      em.Body = "I have to attach a Pie chart that is 25% of it filled"


      Smtp.Send(em)


  Catch error_t As Exception
      MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
  End Try
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to save the Chart image in local filesystem and attach it in the mail as inline attachment and keeping the body as html. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048758/how-to-embed-multiple-images-in-email-body-using-net) SO question for more information.

```
chart1.SaveImage(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// attach the saved image file.
Dim data As New Attachment(fileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
em.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Comment: How do i generate the Pie chart and save in Local file-system ?

Comment: @sharonHwk - I thought you already had the chart. If you haven't worked with MS Chart then go through this nice [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET) and its example project.