# C# - Send email with inline attachment WITHOUT Outlook's paperclip icon?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, inline

I have a system that sends emails with inline pictures. The problem is how Outlook 2013 displays the attachments. Can I update my code in a way that tells outlook **not** to display the paperclip icon seen here?

[image: Outlook 2013 preview pane]

The idea is that I only want to display this icon when full sized pictures are attached. Not inline attachments.

Here's the code that generates the email. Create a basic console app, specify your To / mailserver / picture path, and run.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Prepping email message....");

    var subject = "Test Subject With Inline";
    var message = "<p>This is a test message.</p><br/><br/><p>[CompanyLogo]</p>";
    var to = new List<string>();

    to.Add("My.Name@company.com");

    Console.WriteLine("Sending email message....");

    if (SendMessageToFrom(subject, message, to, new List<string>()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email sent! Check your inbox.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error sending email!");
    }
}

public static bool SendMessageToFrom(String subject, String message, List<String> to, List<String> cc)
{
    try
    {
        // Construct the email
        var sendMessage = new MailMessage()
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            From = new MailAddress("noreply@company.com"),
            Subject = subject,
            Body = message
        };

        if (sendMessage.Body.Contains("[CompanyLogo]"))
        {
            sendMessage.AlternateViews.Add(EmbedLogo(sendMessage.Body));
        }

        // Add the list of recipients
        foreach (var recipient in to)
        {
            sendMessage.To.Add(recipient);
        }
        foreach (var recipient in cc)
        {
            sendMessage.CC.Add(recipient);
        }

        //Specify the SMTP server
        var smtpServerName = "mailserver.company.com";

        var mailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServerName);

        mailClient.Send(sendMessage);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private static AlternateView EmbedLogo(string html)
{
    var inline = new LinkedResource("img\\company-logo.jpg");
    inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    html = html.Replace("[CompanyLogo]", string.Format(@"<img src='cid:{0}'/>", inline.ContentId));
    var result = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    result.LinkedResources.Add(inline);
    return result;
}
```

Update: Here's the code that did the trick:

```
private static MailMessage EmbedLogo(MailMessage mail)
{
    var inline = new Attachment("img\\company-logo.jpg");
    inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
    inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
    mail.Body = mail.Body.Replace("[CompanyLogo]", string.Format(@"<img src='cid:{0}'/>", inline.ContentId));
    mail.Attachments.Add(inline);
    return mail;
}
```

And I also updated the main method to this:

```
if (sendMessage.Body.Contains("[CompanyLogo]"))
{
    sendMessage = EmbedLogo(sendMessage);
}
```

Comment: did this work for you? I am facing same issue. It shows pin icon in outlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your attachments have the Content-ID MIME header and the message's HTML body refers to them using the cid attribute : `<img src="cid:xyz">` (where xyz is the value of the Content-ID MIME header).

Comment: This worked great for me!  Here's the link that did the magic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19139153. Also I'll update the OP to include the working code.