# How to add an api endpoint to HTML src tag

Tags: html, email, .net-core

I am using an API endpoint URL which returns a byte array of content-type: image.

This endpoint will be used in the src attribute of the image tag to display the image.

I am doing this because the image is to be displayed in an email client and the client deletes the src attribute if I use a base64 string

The endpoint I am using has a mandatory correlation-id in the header.

How can I use the endpoint URL in the src attribute of an image tag with the mandatory correlation-id

Comment: Does using an absolute image path in src works?

Comment: You cannot add custom headers to a HTML `<img src="">`. Perhaps you can proxy the request through your own backend that doesn't require the header but requests the image data from the actual endpoint URL after adding the correlation-id header?

Comment: The image is stored in a private bucket so I cannot use the absolute image path in src.  If I use the image data(in base64string) in src google email client strips it out.

Comment: An alternative option would be to attach the image to the email with a [ContentID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139153/1941241) attribute which you can then use in the `<img src="cid:...">`.