# C# - Attach image from upload form to email

Tags: c#, html-email, image-uploading, email-attachments

I have a form which uploads an image to the server, and I am abl to get the filename of the image and other data inside the form.

How would I convert the image to string to be included in a html email?

This is the code which gives me my filename.

```
string PostedFileName = "not_set";
foreach (string fileName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileName];
    PostedFileName = fileName;
}
MessageSent("TRUE - " + PostedFileName);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921275/sending-an-email-with-an-image-embedded-in-the-body-from-c-sharp ?

Comment: @Donnelle that link shows how to embed an image into a html email. I am asking **how to convert this uploaded image to a format which can be embedded** into a html email.

Comment: Is it possible to get file path here? If you are able to get file path we can attach image in the html mail. using alternative view concept.

Comment: I don't want to save the image to the server, I just have it sitting in the HttpContext.Current.Request.Files after being posted via an ajax form.

Comment: https://haseebmukhtar.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/c-embed-images-in-email-embedded-images-not-attachment/