# C# Send Email with <b> and <u>

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to send an email using Bold and Underline in my Message in C#

```
<b></b> <u></u>
```

How would I implement this into my code??

```
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "test");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "test");
    const string fromPassword = "REMOVED";
    const string subject = "Engineering Completed NewParts Project";
    const string body = "Engineering has completed their data entry on the <b><u>NewParts</b></u> project on PDMTool. / ";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
               {
                   Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                   Port = 587,
                   EnableSsl = true,
                   DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                   UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                   Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
               };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                         {
                             Subject = subject,
                             Body = body
                         })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873155/mailmessage-c-sharp-how-to-make-it-html-and-add-images-etc

Comment: Where do i put mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true; //Anywhere???

Comment: [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your new MailMessage declaration like so:

```
new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true  // this tells the message to be sent in HTML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [the `IsBodyHtml` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) to `true`:

```
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true
}
```