# How to get the link of attached files in Email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I want to send an email with some attached images. I also need to show these images in Email. How can I get the link of these attached email so that I can show them in email.

Note: I can also use remote images, but email servers like yahoo, gmail and hotmail will put them in spam.

Is this is possible in ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question with a solution using the [`AlternateView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview.aspx) class:

[sending mail along with embedded image using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net)

```
string html = @"<html><body><img src=""cid:YourPictureId""></body></html>";
AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

LinkedResource yourPictureRes = new LinkedResource("yourPicture.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
yourPictureRes.ContentId = "YourPictureId";
altView.LinkedResources.Add(yourPicture);

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
```