# Why is my image not showing in the email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have an ecard application that allows a user to pick an image and send an email. But I am not able to figure out how to send the email here is my code.

```
protected void SendEmail()
{
    StringBuilder message;
    Attachment attachFile;
    string sImage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/KDMC_EcardList/images/" + txtCapture.Text);
    LinkedResource yourPictureRes = new LinkedResource(txtCapture.Text, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    yourPictureRes.ContentId = "YourPictureId";
    altView.LinkedResources.Add(yourPictureRes);
    //Internal Message
    message = new StringBuilder();
    message.AppendLine(@"<p><img src=cid: sImage /></p>");
    message.AppendLine(@"<pre><table style='width:650px; word-break:break-word; height:auto;'>
                             </td><tr><td style='width:150px;'>From: </td><td style='width:500px;'>" + txtFName.Text + " " + txtLName.Text + @"
                            </td><tr><td>To: </td><td>" + txtFriendFName.Text + " " + txtFriendLName.Text + @"
                            </td><tr><td>Room Number: </td><td>" + txtRoom.Text + @"
                           </td><tr><td>Message: </td><td>" + txtMessage.Text + @"                                 
                           </td><tr><td>Date Sent: </td><td>" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "</td></tr></table></pre>");

    //attachFile = new Attachment(FileUploadVideo.PostedFile.InputStream, strFileName);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // need to create new reference to attachment, cannot use same reference to send email twice
    //attachment = new Attachment(theMemoryStream, strSubject);
    Mail.SendMail("test@test.net", "test@test.net", "", "test@test.net",
            "test@test.net", MailPriority.Normal, "A new Ecard has been submitted", MailFormat.Html, Encoding.UTF8, message.ToString(),
            new List<Attachment>() { }, null, null, null, null, Host.EnableSMTPSSL);  
}
```

I tried to follow the example here [C# add image to email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139157/c-sharp-add-image-to-email-body) as well as other solutions in the community but I am still unable to find a solution.

Comment: The post that post links to seems to be more what you're after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [embedded image to the email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net) , then you can use the `cid` id in the template:

```
LinkedResource yourPictureRes = new LinkedResource("yourPicture.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
yourPictureRes.ContentId = "YourPictureId";
altView.LinkedResources.Add(yourPictureRes);
```

Comment: I get the part about adding the picture name, but what would be `YourPictureId`. Also does this mean that I do not need to use `<img src=cid: sImage /></p>`?

Comment: The id can be any text - try `img1` for example, or `YourPictureId` as in the linked example.

Comment: I have edited my code above to reflect what you asked me to try. It is giving an error on the `altview` line.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the CID of the IMG tag's src to the result of `Server.MapPath(...)`.  This will be a full path on your machine.  I think what needs to go in there if you're referring to the attachment is the filename (`Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(...))`)