# Send email with img attachment in asp.net to a user with mac mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am attempting to attach image files to emails sent by my website.

I have followed the method used here

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-with-img-asp4-cs/

This is the code I have written

```
    string smtpServer = "my server";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    string img = "/img/emails/test.png";


    Attachment imgAtt = new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(img));

    imgAtt.ContentId = Path.GetFileName(img);
    //add the attachment to the email
    message.Attachments.Add(imgAtt);

    message.From = new MailAddress("example@example.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("otherexample@example.com"));
    message.Subject = "test";
    message.Body = "<img src=\"cid:test.png\">";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    client.Send(message);
```

This is working fine accept when the person receiving the email uses Mac Mail.  In this case the image is displayed twice when the person views the email.  Is there a solution to this problem?

Edit:  I have tried the solution on [sending mail along with embedded image using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113345/sending-mail-along-with-embedded-image-using-asp-net).  However I have had the same outcome.  Users with mac mail still see the image twice.

Comment: You want to attach images.. this is a simple attachment.. why are you then trying to embed that in the body? You either attach, or use an alternate view to embed. Not both.

Comment: This is just test code.  On my website I need to send an email that has images that are positioned using html.  Hence simply attaching is not enough.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Thanks very much.  I think you're right about it being a dupe.  My search strategy obviously needs to be improved!