# How to add html formatting to an email in C#?

Tags: c#, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating HTML email body in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886728/generating-html-email-body-in-c)

My client as some specific formatting requirements. The email should look something like this:

```
                                     Hi there!
A friend of yours, <Name>, wanted to make sure you know about us. You may already
know about who we are and what we do,we...

                         ...kick ass because we can
                         ...do all of our financing

                             So please reach us at

                                blah blah blah
```

I am using string variable and have added `<br />` `<p>` html tags to where ever needed, but I am not able to style attribute information.  Can some one please help me with this? I was thinking of adding `style="text-align:center;"` to the tags.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your email-sending code look like so far?

Comment: @alecgorge: your edit broke the br & p tags in the last paragraph

Comment: @Adam V Sorry about that. I guess we edited the post at the same time. It has been fixed.