# How I can send a html mail in ASP.NET with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, email, smtp

I have a ASP.NET Application that add data to a DataBase and get data from this database. This Application is for creating a guestconnection to our network. If a User is add to the database and the Radius Server give the ok the User get e email with his login data. username and password. I want to make a html mail. But I don't know how I can do this in ASP.NET and so I read a few tutorials about that and I found this Code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12182/ASP-NET-Sending-mail-using-SMTP-in-HTML-format-us

this is my code:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To = "<here is my company email>";
                mail.From = "test@domain.de";
                mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
                mail.Subject = "testheader";
                mail.Body =
                    "<html><body><Table><tr><td>Hi,</td></tr><tr><td>Details of the Statistics :</td></tr></Table></body></html><html><body>" +
                    "sometext" +
                    "</body></html><html><body><Table><tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>NOTE: This is an automated mail. Please, do not reply.</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>*Green coloured rows indicates temporary demos</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>**All statistics are based on the page naming conventions Eg., 22_10_2005_</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Regards,</td></tr><tr><td>some text,</td></tr><tr><td>some text,</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td> Some text </td></tr></table></body></html>";

                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "<smtp ip>";
                SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

I try this and get the error that:

```
The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.1 Client not authenticated
```

The Ip is right but what I must do for the authenticated..how i can do this?

Comment: By the way, you can use the `MailDefinition` class to generate the HTML body. It's a little easier than string concatenation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/886750/2972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the [SMTP server mailSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx) in your `Web.config` file:

```
  <system.net >
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="someaddress@classifiedspak.com">
        <network
        host="mail.classifiedspak.com"
        userName="someaddress@classifiedspak.com "
        password="*************"
        port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```