# sending html content within email body

Tags: asp.net, html, email

i nearly spent a day on it but couldn't fix it,

i am sending HTML within email body (asp.net 3.5) but problem is that it neither it takes div within body nor any inline style ,

```
message.Body = "<html>"+
                               "<body>"+
                                 "<div style=\"background-color:yellow;\">" +
                                  "<h3>"+
                                   " Congrats" + " " + userName + " " + " You have been shortlisted for interview. Please appear on " + " " + date +", "+time+" "+ "for interview"+
                                  "</h3>"+
                                 "</div>"+
                                "</body>"+
                               "</html>";
```

the tags for bold works well, / , but it doesn't take any style or even div tag within body, why ?

Comment: Can you include your full Send code? What email client are you checking in? Also consider [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) when concatenating a lot of strings. Or in this case, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886728/generating-html-email-body-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Set the IsHTML flag to true on the MailMessage.

Comment: i already set that to true message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                   
but no effect :(

Comment: Post the full code for your method like @MikeSmithDev suggests. I seem to remember that this wasn't as straightforward as it should be and there were a couple of hoops you had to jump through.