# HTML in email body showing as HTML itself. Not rendering ASP.NET Mail

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient, asp.net-mail

Im facing a little trouble when sending emails from ASP.NET (VB). Here is the code Im on

```
            Using mm As New MailMessage("myemai@abcd.com", mc.mailTo)

                If mc.mailCC.Trim <> "" Then
                    mm.CC.Add(mc.mailCC)
                End If
                If mc.mailBCC.Trim <> "" Then
                    mm.CC.Add(mc.mailBCC)
                End If
                mm.IsBodyHtml = True
                mm.Subject = mc.mailSubject
                mm.Body = b
                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient() 


                Try
                    smtp.Send(mm)
                Catch ex As SmtpException
                    gf.logArray(jA, ex.Message)
                    Dim statuscode As SmtpStatusCode
                    statuscode = ex.StatusCode
                    If statuscode = SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy Or statuscode = SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable Or statuscode = SmtpStatusCode.TransactionFailed Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                        smtp.Send(mm)

                    End If


                End Try

            End Using
```

The issue am having is. The mails are sending fine. but the body is showing as just HTML. Not rendering even I clearly specified **mm.isBodyHTML=true**. Any suggestions please...

THis is the message I got

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886728/generating-html-email-body-in-c-sharp

Comment: What I just found is its happening only with specific mail servers. In my case we are using mailjet. But when I tried to use gmail, it works absolute fine. So something strange regarding mail server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using smtp for sending email you can add one parameter IsBodyHtml, I was facing same issue and fixed by setting IsBodyHtml=true and it works for me.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "Abc Noreply");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(email, "");
        const string fromPassword = "acbsexample";



        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = emailBody,
            IsBodyHtml=true
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem is in you html message body. Try send in message body only table with content, without DOCTYPE, head and other content.

Becouse mail agent render your message in already exist html page, so couldn`t render page in page a agent encode your message body as a string.

Comment: Thats sounds to be a reason.. Will try and update you.. Thanks